# How to replace parts of a text with evaluation result

Tags: linux, bash

I want to replace each occurrence of `@(some str)` in a string with the result of `date --date="some str" +%s`. Where 'some str' can be anything that is passed as is to the --date argument. Note that I want to support several `@()` occurrences.

For example, the string `from @(-1 week) to @(-1 day)` should become `from 1435830929 to 1436349343`. And if I evaluate it in one week, it should be `from 1436435800 to 1436954213`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

see [match and replace one pattern multiple times in the same line delimited by unknown characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31403141/match-and-replace-one-pattern-multiple-times-in-the-same-line-delimited-by-unkno)

Basically:

```
sed -r 's|@\(([^)]*)\)|$(date +%s --date "now\1")|g; s|.*|echo "&"|e' <<< input_string
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you expecting something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash

str="@2147483647 some other string @2147483647"
from="@2147483647"
to="$(date --date @2147483647)"

echo ${str//$from/$to}
```

Comment: Well, if I wanted to replace a constant string with something else, I wouldn't need to write a script. I'd just evaluate what my other values should be and write  a new constant string