# match and replace one pattern multiple times in the same line delimited by unknown characters

Tags: linux, bash, perl

Given the input of the form:

```
select * from foo where ts>@(-2 days) and ts < @(-1 hour)
```

(this is of course just an example. I want to support any query construct and any expression in @())

I want to replace the expression in every `@()` with the result of evaluating `date --date=exp +%s`, where 'exp' is the expression (so in the example above the result will be

```
select * from foo where ts>1436694136 and ts < 1436863336
```

More generally, how do I replace a pattern with the result of invoking a shell command with captures from the pattern as arguments?

(I've tagged the question with perl, and bash, but am open to anything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using gnu sed:

```
$ sql_expr="select * from foo where ts>@(-2 days) and ts < @(-1 hour)"

$ sed -r 's|@\(([^)]*)\)|$(date +%s --date "now\1")|g; s|.*|echo "&"|e' <<< "$sql_expr"

Gave:
select * from foo where ts>1436696209 and ts < 1436865409
```

Note that this code assumes that the contents of `@(...)` are valid expressions, for date calculations.

Explanation:

1. First expression will replace all `@()` occurrences with `$(date +%s --date "now _expression_")` where `_expression_` is going to be something like `-2 days`.
2. Second replace expression adds `echo "..."` around entire string & *executes* the generated line. You can remove the `e` flag in second expression to find out what command gets executed actually.

Answer (score 1):

Something like below (untested)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $date1;
my $date2;
my $expr = q{select * from foo where ts>@(-2 days) and ts < @(-1 hour)};
if( $expr =~ m#\@\((.*?)\) and .*? \@\((.*?)\)# ){
    $date1 = $1;
    $date2 = $2;
}
my $expr1 = `date --date=$date1 +%s`;
my $expr2 = `date --date=$date2 +%s`;

#now search and replace the $expr

$expr =~ s#\@\((.*?)\)#$expr1;
$expr =~ s#< \@\((.*?)\)#<.$expr2;

print "Final expression is $expr\n";
```